# How to turn dict in a list into a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to turn the list like this:

```
[{u'host': u'node54', u'key': u'cpu_load_average_limit', u'value': 4.0}, 
 {u'host': u'node54', u'key': u'ram_allocation_ratio', u'value': 4.0}, 
 {u'host': u'node54', u'key': u'cpu_allocation_ratio', u'value': 4.0},
 {u'host': u'node53', u'key': u'cpu_load_average_limit', u'value': 4.0}, 
 {u'host': u'node53', u'key': u'ram_allocation_ratio', u'value': 4.0}, 
 {u'host': u'node53', u'key': u'cpu_allocation_ratio', u'value': 4.0}]
```

into:

```
{u'node54': {u'cpu_allocation_ratio': 4.0, u'ram_allocation_ratio': 4.0, u'cpu_load_average_limit': 4.0}, 
 u'node53': {u'cpu_allocation_ratio': 4.0, u'ram_allocation_ratio': 4.0, u'cpu_load_average_limit': 4.0}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
entries = [
 {u'host': u'node54', u'key': u'cpu_load_average_limit', u'value': 4.0}, 
 {u'host': u'node54', u'key': u'ram_allocation_ratio', u'value': 4.0}, 
 {u'host': u'node54', u'key': u'cpu_allocation_ratio', u'value': 4.0},
 {u'host': u'node53', u'key': u'cpu_load_average_limit', u'value': 4.0}, 
 {u'host': u'node53', u'key': u'ram_allocation_ratio', u'value': 4.0}, 
 {u'host': u'node53', u'key': u'cpu_allocation_ratio', u'value': 4.0}
]

result = {}
for entry in entries:
    result.setdefault(entry['host'], {})[entry['key']] = entry['value']

assert result == {u'node54': {u'cpu_allocation_ratio': 4.0, u'ram_allocation_ratio': 4.0, u'cpu_load_average_limit': 4.0}, u'node53': {u'cpu_allocation_ratio': 4.0, u'ram_allocation_ratio': 4.0, u'cpu_load_average_limit': 4.0}}
```